# How can I unset submit button duration the refresh

Tags: php, codeigniter

In codeigniter,After submitting a form,My values are stored into database.But after giving refresh it is stored again with same data.How can i solve it?
Please help me.

Comment: What do you expect instead?

Comment: You might want to look at the concept of Post/Redirect/Get: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Post/Redirect/Get

Comment: @AmalMurali I am talking about Duplicate form submissions.

Answer (score 1):

After the successful storation of data, in the controller, use `redirect('controller/method', 'refresh')` function.